# Duhamel's formulation of a pde

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let's consider the following initial value problem
$$u_t=Lu+F,\,\,\,\,u(0)=u_0$$ with $L$ a spatial operator.
Which are the minimal assumptions on $F$,$u_0$,$u$ to have the equivalence of the problem with its Duhamel's formulation
$$u=e^{tL}u_0+\int_0^te^{(t-s)L}F(s)ds$$?

Comment: What you have posted is essentially an algebraic identity-independent of the function spaces on which the operators are defined. I can see no way in which you could reason about whether or not all symbols had meaning unless you gave some more to $L$. I'd say as it stands, all you can assume is that $u_{0}, F \in \mathrm{dom}(L)$. However, give $L$ some more properties and then the "minimal assumptions" will be more interesting.